# TypeError: Cannot read property 'mergeConfig' of undefined

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

When running gulp via cmd I get this error :

[image: TypeError: Cannot read property 'mergeConfig' of undefined]

Below is my `package.json`

```js
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-install": "^0.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-11",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack": "^1.0.1",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to show your `gulpfile.js` or we can't help you.

Comment: @Martin Fixed this issue by running npm install --no-bin-links. BTW thanks for reaching out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by running:

```
npm install --no-bin-links
```